# Unique CellID in-between notebooks

Tags: cells

Documentation says that CellID is guaranteed to be unique for a given notebook.
I've noticed that CellID are fairly high numbers and although probabilistically speaking the odds of coincidence are low, how can I modify its behaviour to have a guarantee of no repetitions in-between notebooks?

For simplification let's assume that it should only hold for notebooks created on my machine and not ones downloaded from the internet etc.